# Calculating the units of pressure in General Relativity, knowing $G=M=c=1$

Tags: general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, units, dimensional-analysis

I'm trying to figure out how large  Pressure units compared to the standard CGS model is when taken $G=M=c=1$

What I have been thinking is: $$\dfrac{GM\rho}{r^2} = - \nabla P$$ or $$\|G\| \mathrm{\dfrac{dyn\cdot cm^2}{gr ^2}}\cdot\|M\|\ \mathrm{gr}\cdot \|\rho\| \mathrm{\dfrac{gr}{cm^3}} \cdot \dfrac{1}{\|r^2\|\ \mathrm{cm^2}}= -\dfrac{[P]}{r}$$
but from there, what is the next step to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, because $M$ is not a dimensional physical constant, but a free variable that depends on the situation in question - namely, the mass of some gravitating object and thus what in effect you're doing is to take *that particular object* as your unit of mass.

There are no other dimensional physical constants in pure general relativity alone but $G$ and $c$, so there is no way to define a purely natural unit of pressure within it since, as you have observed, you need three kinetic dimensions to build it.

Unless you have a specific mass scale in mind, this won't work.

**ADD:** In the comments below, the OP has suggested that the mass is indeed to be variable and that given for the gravitating object. In that case, we can figure out the relevant pressure units by dimensional analysis. The dimensions of pressure are

$$\text{[Pressure]} = \text{[M]} \text{[L]}^{-1} \text{[T]}^{-2}$$

while those of $G$ and $c$ are

$$[G] = \text{[M]}^{-1} \text{[L]}^3 \text{[T]}^{-2}$$
$$[c] = \text{[L]} \text{[T]}^{-1}$$

Hence we consider the constant combination $G^n c^m M^p$ so that

$$\begin{align}
[G^n c^m M^p] &= \left(\text{[M]}^{-1} \text{[L]}^3 \text{[T]}^{-2}\right)^n \cdot \left(\text{[L]} \text{[T]}^{-1}\right)^m \cdot \left(\text{[M]}\right)^p\\
&= \left(\text{[M]}^{-n} \text{[L]}^{3n} \text{[T]}^{-2n}\right) \cdot \left(\text{[L]}^m \text{[T]}^{-m}\right) \cdot \left(\text{[M]}^p\right)\\
&= \text{[M]}^{-n+p} \text{[L]}^{3n + m} \text{[T]}^{-2n - m}\\
&= \text{[Pressure]}
\end{align}$$

and matching we see we need $-n + p = 1$, $3n + m = -1$, and $-2n - m = -2$. Adding the last two equations together gives $n = -3$, hence from the first we get $p = -2$, and then either of the last again gives $m = 8$. Thus the "natural" pressure associated with this mass $M$ is

$$P_\mathrm{nat} = \frac{c^8}{G^3 M^2} \approx \left(2.19 \times 10^{98}\ \mathrm{\frac{Pa}{kg^{-2}}}\right) \cdot M^{-2}$$

. For a mass of $1\ M_\odot \approx 1.98 \times 10^{30}\ \mathrm{kg}$ this is about $5.6 \times 10^{37}\ \mathrm{Pa}$ (you can convert that to $\mathrm{dyn/cm^2}$; I don't use CGS.), and each 10-fold increase in mass cuts it by 100 times.

Comment: If $G=c=1$ then how would I proceed? (The mass scale is the Black Hole Mass)

Comment: @billy : Added.

Comment: Really thanks. It come pretty useful and helped me! Much appreciated